# Adjective for 'a description that permits different people to envision the same event'

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that implies that a description of a complex and intricate event enables different people to envision that event and ascribe more or less the same features to it.

**Example sentence:**
It should be possible to provide a ***ADJECTIVE HERE*** description that allows the different, unrelated, and dispersed experiencers and aspirants to form a relatively coherent picture of the event.

NOTE, adjectives such as these here below are excluded:

- precise
- detailed
- rich
- all-encompassing
- profound

Thanks for any conducive input!

Comment: Intricate? Full? Telling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is an adjective that conveys that complex concept. Sometimes you need more than one word to convey a thought; otherwise any book longer than one word would be verbose and redundant.

But "universally comprehensible" or "humanly comprehensible" should work.

By the way, and this is an unsolicited opinion, I do not think "coherent" expresses your intended thought: please consider "consistent." And the phrase "different, unrelated, and dispersed experiencers and aspirants" sounds like pretentious jargon. As I decipher what you are trying to say, I get to

> It should be possible to provide a description that all aspirants, whatever their different experiences and cultural backgrounds, would interpret consistently.

as being most likely, but I cannot be sure